# Query performances by evaluating Execution Plan (Join First Row)

Tags: sql-server, performance, sqlfiddle

I have the following tables:

**Customers**

```
ID     Name 
============
1      John 
2      Alice
3      Bob
```

**Orders**

```
ID     CustomerID   Status
==========================
1001       1          1
1002       2          1
1003       2          2
1004       3          2
```

I'd like to join tables showing one entry per customer only (the one with lowest Status) i.e.

```
ID     Name    OrderID 
======================
1      John     1001
2      Alice    1002
3      Bob      1004
```

Thanks to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043259/how-to-join-to-first-row), I chose 2 solutions which produce the same output:

**Solution 1**

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, o.id FROM customers AS c
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON
c.id =  o.customerid
WHERE o.status = (SELECT MIN(status) FROM orders WHERE customerid = c.id)
```

**Solution 2**

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, o.id FROM customers as c
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON
o.id = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM orders WHERE customerid = c.id ORDER BY status)
```

Trying to understand which one runs faster, I used [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) View Execution Plan which gave the following:

**Solution 1**

[image: Solution 1]

**Solution 2**

[image: Solution 2]

How to interpret those diagrams and which one performs faster?
Using MS SQL Server 2016.

Comment: The execution plan doesn't tell you how fast it runs. You want [set-statistics-time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for that.

Comment: Dale is correct (and/or use recent versions of SSMS, which include times on the Actual execution plans). However, I'm pretty certain the first one will be faster - the first solution has 2 table scans, while the second solution has 3 table scans, two of which are within a nested loop join (e.g., it may be run many many times).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my breakdown and the last one is my suggestion to you.

Query Cost 67%

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, o.id FROM @Customers AS c
INNER JOIN @Orders AS o ON
c.id =  o.customerid
WHERE o.status = (SELECT MIN(status) FROM @Orders WHERE customerid = c.id)
```

Query Cost 66%

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, o.id FROM @Customers as c
INNER JOIN @Orders AS o ON
o.id = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM @Orders WHERE customerid = c.id ORDER BY status)
```

Query Cost 47%

```
SELECT
  x.CustID,
  x.Name,
  x.OrderID
FROM (SELECT
  C.id CustID,
  c.Name,
  o.ID OrderID,
  o.status,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY o.status) rn
FROM @Customers c
INNER JOIN @Orders o
  ON o.CustomerID    = c.ID) x
WHERE x.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. But what query cost mean? Percentage of what?

Comment: @kuma  Query cost is what optimizer thinks of how long your query will take (relative to total batch time). The optimizer tries to choose the optimal query plan by looking at your query and statistics of your data, trying several execution plans and selecting the least costly of them

Comment: sorry it's still unclear what 100% represents in these 3 cases

Comment: @kuma I take it you don't understand english very well. to simplify, Ideal query performance means less query cost.

Comment: this has nothing to do with english. As the percentage is relative to the batch, _what is the batch_ in your examples? If the batch comprises the 3 queries, their query costs don't add up to 100% as [it should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191356/query-cost-relative-to-batch-is-100)

Comment: @kuma that's what you did not get... Query Cost is simply the amount of effort SQL performed your batch request.. less cost meaning faster query. this is not math where need to add something up to 100%.